# Discord Bot waiting for multiple user input

Tags: python, api, input, command, discord

Okay so, i have a bot that simply reacts to a single message.

user sends input.
bot sends output.
command done.

however i want the bot to for example ask the user something back
user sends input.
bot sends question: "are you sure you want to XXXXXX"
user sends 2. input.
bot sends output.

i am not sure tho how to make the bot wait for a second user message inside of one command.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a check before it.

```
def check(message, user):
  return message.channel == ctx.message.channel and user.author == ctx.message.author
reply = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
```

Like this.